Prove that if $p \le q$ then $W_p(\mu,\nu) \le W_q(\mu,\nu)$, where $W_p$ denote the Wasserstein distance

Given two numbers $p,q$ such that $1 \le p \le q$. Prove that
\begin{align*} W_p(\mu,\nu) \le W_q(\mu,\nu), \end{align*} where $W_p$ denotes the Wasserstein distance of order $p$.

My solution: Given two numbers $p,q$ such that $1\le p \le q$. By Holder's inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
    \int_{\Omega\times \Omega} \vert x-y\vert^p \mathrm{d}\pi \le \left(\int_{\Omega\times \Omega} \vert x-y\vert^q \mathrm{d}\pi\right)^{p/q}\left(\int_{\Omega\times \Omega} 1 \mathrm{d}\pi\right)^{1-p/q}
\end{align*}
Hence, we can deduce that
\begin{align*}
    \left(\int_{\Omega\times \Omega} \vert x-y\vert^p \mathrm{d}\pi\right)^{1/p} \le \left(\int_{\Omega\times \Omega} \vert x-y\vert^q \mathrm{d}\pi\right)^{1/q}.
\end{align*}
By taking the minimum with respect to $\pi$ over $\Omega \times \Omega$, we claim that
\begin{align*}
    W_{p}(\mu,\nu) \le W_q(\mu,\nu).
\end{align*}
I wonder if my solution is correct or not. In addition, in the Optimal Transport book of Santambrogio (page 179), they also mention using Jensen's inequality for this problem. I am a bit curious about that direction and am welcome if you could give me some hints on that.

Let us write
$$W_q(\mu, \nu) = \inf_{\gamma \in \Gamma(\mu, \nu)} \left(\mathbf{E}_{(x, y) \sim \gamma} d(x, y)^q \right)^{1/q}.  $$
Then, for $p<q$, from Jensen's inequality we have
$$\left(\mathbf{E}_{(x, y) \sim \gamma} d(x, y)^p \right)^{1/q} \\=\left(\mathbf{E}_{(x, y) \sim \gamma} \left (d(x, y)^{p}\right)^{\frac q p} \right)^{1/q} \\ \ge \left(\left( \mathbf{E}_{(x, y) \sim \gamma}  (d(x, y)^{p})\right)^{\frac q p} \right)^{1/q} \\ =\left(\mathbf{E}_{(x, y) \sim \gamma} d(x, y)^p \right)^{1/p},$$
which establishes $$W_p(\mu, \nu) \le W_q(\mu, \nu).$$

I got your point. Thank you very much!
